# Как правильно передать параметры этому Go коду?

Tags: golang, yaml

Проект  https://github.com/ffddorf/unms-exporter/blob/main/main.go

```go
type config struct {
    ServerAddr string       `mapstructure:"listen" split_words:"true"`
    LogLevel   logrus.Level `mapstructure:"log_level" split_words:"true"`

    TokenPerHost map[string]string `mapstructure:"token" envconfig:"-"`
}

const envPrefix = "UNMS_EXPORTER"
```

По сути оба параметра ( адрес и токен) строки

```
---
listen: "ip_addr"
token: "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

Но при запуске выдает ошибку

```
/usr/local/bin/unms-exporter -c  /etc/unms-exporter/config.yml
FATA[0000] failed to read config from flags              error="1 error(s) decoding:\n\n* 'token' expected a map, got 'string'"
```

Собственно и непонятно как в кофиге указать токен для
map[string]string `mapstructure:"token" envconfig:"-"`

Comment: у вас получается массив данных вида `[]SomeObj{ ServerAddr, TokenPerHost string}`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor а как в это будет выглядеть в виде yaml?

Answer (score 0):

если вы хотите исключительно map[string]string, то вам нужно иметь структуру вида

```
---
listen: "ip_addr"
token:
    "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx": "value"
    "xxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyy": "value"
```